# Unable to use substring and index of() to get the substring and put a null check on it

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, substring, indexof

i m unable to use indexof() and substring to get the value of the string .

[image]

the value of customname is variable but it is coming in the form of string. I want to put a null check on custom name how can i do this.

```
  string customFolders = context.Request["customFolders"];
        int i = 0;
        string customname = context.Request["customName"];
        if (i = customFolders.IndexOf("customname",-1))
        {

        }
```

Comment: Please post your code, not screenshots of it!

Comment: You say "I want to put a null check on custom name;" what's wrong with `if (customname == null)`?

Comment: @DanPuzey can't use that if u check the screenshot customname is a part of string i m getting in variable customFolders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very unclear what you want to do because on the one hand you mention you want to use *Substring* and *IndexOf*, and on the other hand, you put it on comment and say you want to check if it's null, and which you're already checking if the string *customFolders* is null or empty. I am very confused, but I can tell you that if you want to use *String.IndexOf* with 2 parameters (a string and an int), the int parameter has to be greater or equal to 0 and less than the string's length because this parameter is the index of which it will start searching for the specified string.

Also if you try to execute the *if* statement that you posted, it will generate a compile error since you are giving the result of the *IndexOf* to the variable *i*, but what about the value of this? You do not check the value so the statement results an int value, but an *if* statement requires a boolean value.

Hopefully that helped you somewhat.

Comment: Yes what u r saying is correct and i was getting error but yoour answer will be more helpful if you could correct the code.

Comment: I can't do that for you since you're the one who knows what you want to do, I just tried to give the knowledge you need in order to do it.
But try something like this `if ((i = customFolders.IndexOf("customname",wantedStartIndex)) > -1)`

If you want to search the whole string then _wantedStartIndex_ should be 0